# std::strings's capacity(), reserve() & resize() functions

Tags: c++, string, stl

I wan to use std::string simply to create a dynamic buffer and than iterate through it using an index. Is resize() the only function to actually allocate the buffer?

I tried reserve() but when I try to access the string via index it asserts. Also when the string's default capacity seems to be 15 bytes (in my case) but if I still can't access it as `my_string[1]`.

So the capacity of the string is not the actual buffer? Also reserve() also does't allocate the actual buffer?

```
string my_string;

// I want my string to have 20 bytes long buffer
my_string.reserve( 20 );

int i = 0;

for ( parsing_something_else_loop )
{
    char ch = <business_logic>;

    // store the character in 
    my_string[i++] = ch; // this crashes
}
```

If I do resize() instead of reserve() than it works fine. How is it that the string has the capacity but can't really access it with []? Isn't that the point to reserve() size so you can access it?

**Add-on**
In response to the answers, I would like to ask stl folks, Why would anybody use reserve() when resize() does exactly the same and it also initialize the string? I have to say I don't appreciate the performance argument in this case that much. All that resize() does additional to what reserve() does is that it merely initialize the buffer which we know is always nice to do anyways. Can we vote reserve() off the island?

Comment: Would a byte vector be more appropriate

Comment: **std::vector** seem also a possible solution for your requirements. Would a answer with std::vector also be an acceptable answer?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> Isn't that the point to reserve() size so you can access it?

No, that's the point of `resize()`.

`reserve()` only gives to enough room so that future call that leads to increase of the size (e.g. calling `push_back()`) will be more efficient.

From your use case it looks like you should use `.push_back()` instead.

```
my_string.reserve( 20 );

for ( parsing_something_else_loop )
{
    char ch = <business_logic>;
    my_string.push_back(ch);
}
```

---

> How is it that the string has the capacity but can't really access it with []?

Calling `.reserve()` is like blowing up mountains to give you some free land. The amount of free land is the `.capacity()`. The land is there but that doesn't mean you can live there. You have to build houses in order to move in. The number of houses is the `.size()` (= `.length()`).

Suppose you are building a city, but after building the 50th you found that there is not enough land, so you need to found another place large enough to fit the 51st house, and then migrate the whole population there. This is extremely inefficient. If you knew you need to build 1000 houses up-front, then you can call

```
my_string.reserve(1000);
```

to get enough land to build 1000 houses, and then you call

```
my_string.push_back(ch);
```

to construct the house with the assignment of `ch` to this location. The capacity is 1000, but the size is still 1. You may not say

```
my_string[16] = 'c';
```

because the house #16 does not exist yet. You may call

```
my_string.resize(20);
```

to get houses #0 ~ #19 built in one go, which is why

```
my_string[i++] = ch;
```

works fine (as long as 0 ≤ *i* ≤ 19).

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array.

---

**For your add-on question,**

`.resize()` cannot completely replace `.reserve()`, because (1) you don't always need to use up all allocated spaces, and (2) default construction + copy assignment is a two-step process, which could take more time than constructing directly (esp. for large objects), i.e.

```
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>

struct SlowObject
{
    SlowObject() { sleep(1); }
    SlowObject(const SlowObject& other) { sleep(1); }
    SlowObject& operator=(const SlowObject& other) { sleep(1); return *this; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<SlowObject> my_vector;

    my_vector.resize(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++ i)
        my_vector[i] = SlowObject();

    return 0;
}
```

Will waste you at least 9 seconds to run, while

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<SlowObject> my_vector;

    my_vector.reserve(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++ i)
        my_vector.push_back(SlowObject());

    return 0;
}
```

wastes only 6 seconds.

`std::string` only copies `std::vector`'s interface here.

Comment: Think of it this way: the string still has a size, which has not been changed by `reserve()`; however, you have allocated a contiguous chunk of memory so that the string may be `resize()`'d without incurring a copying of the whole string. It will still, however, check that your index is in bounds with the (logical) size of the string. Reserve is an optimization when you have some ahead-of-time knowledge about how big the string gets - it's like the c idiom of char[1000] - you have 1000 bytes available even though the string may only be "Hello, world"

Comment: So lets say I start out with your example with 'my_string.resize(1000)', what's the performance hit really? I will argue it is better because it reduce one line in the code (the resize() later on) so I have less code to manage.

Comment: @KennyTM your add-on example is about vector but I only want to restrict to string class. In any way OOP is all about objects and object initialization is fundamental part of it. Are we going to disregard OOP principals to achieve marginally better efficiency?

Comment: @zadane: You could have `std::basic_string<SlowObject>`. OOP is about encapsulation, inheritance and polymorphism, but object initialization, and `std::string` has nothing to do with OOP.

Comment: @zadane: Besides, because of *backward compatibility*, it is almost impossible to remove any feature from C++, even if it is illogical now. (trigraphs, `vector<bool>`, `strstream`, etc.)

Comment: @KennyTM I didn't mean it literally to remove it but I wanted to see if developer community agrees that resize() is just better after all and maybe reserve() is not worthy of any praise songs for efficiency.

Comment: @zadane: Then you'd better ask that over http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or in the chatroom.

Comment: @KennyTM I think I will ask it in the same forum but highlighting this issue particularly.

Answer (score 6):

No -- the point of `reserve` is to prevent re-allocation. `resize` sets the usable size, `reserve` does not -- it just sets an amount of space that's reserved, but not yet directly usable.

Here's one example -- we're going to create a 1000-character random string:

```
static const int size = 1000;
std::string x;
x.reserve(size);
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
   x.push_back((char)rand());
```

`reserve` is *primarily* an optimization tool though -- most code that works with `reserve` should also work (just, possibly, a little more slowly) without calling `reserve`. The one exception to that is that `reserve` can ensure that iterators remain valid, when they wouldn't without the call to reserve.

Answer (score 4):

The `capacity` *is* the length of the actual buffer, but that buffer is *private* to the string; in other words, it is not yours to access. The `std::string` of the standard library *may* allocate more memory than is required to storing the actual characters of the string. The capacity is the total allocated length. However, accessing characters outside `s.begin()` and `s.end()` is still illegal.

You call `reserve` in cases when you anticipate resizing of the string to avoid unnecessary re-allocations. For example, if you are planning to concatenate ten 20-character strings in a loop, it may make sense to reserve 201 characters (an extra one is for the zero terminator) for your string, rather than expanding it several times from its default size.

Answer (score 2):

`reserve(n)` indeed allocates enough storage to hold at least `n` elements, but it doesn't actually fill the container with any elements. The string is still empty (has size 0), but you are guaranteed, that you can add (e.g. through `push_back` or `insert`) at least `n` elements before the string's internal buffer needs to be reallocated, whereas `resize(n)` really resizes the string to contain `n` elements (and deletes or adds new elements if neccessary).

So `reserve` is actually a mere optimization facility, when you know you are adding a bunch of elements to the container (e.g. in a `push_back` loop) and don't want it to reallocate the storage too often, which incurs memory allocation and copying costs. But it doesn't change the outside/client view of the string. It still stays empty (or keeps its current element count).

Likewise `capacity` returns the number of elements the string can hold until it needs to reallocate its internal storage, whereas `size` (and for string also `length`) returns the actual number of elements in the string.

Answer (score 1):

**`std::vector`** instead of `std::string` might also be a solution - if there are no requirements against it.

```
vector<char> v; // empty vector
vector<char> v(10); // vector with space for 10 elements, here char's
```

Your example:

```
vector<char> my_string(20);

int i=0;

for ( parsing_something_else_loop )
{
    char ch = <business_logic>;
    my_string[i++] = ch;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's actual question, but merely transforms it into a completely indentical problem.

Comment: I asked in a comment below the question if std::vector might be an option, saw no yes or no and offered an alternative solution, even marked is, as a alternative ("std::vector instead of std::string might also be a solution"). I don't see the harm that you see.

Comment: I don't see any harm, too, as long as comments stay comments and answers stay answers. But your "answer" is just a comment, though a good one, but still a comment and not an answer to any of his questions.

Answer (score 1):

Just because `reserve` allocates additional space does not mean it is legitimate for you to access it.

In your example, either use `resize`, or rewrite it to something like this:

```
string my_string;

// I want my string to have 20 bytes long buffer
my_string.reserve( 20 );

int i = 0;

for ( parsing_something_else_loop )
{
    char ch = <business_logic>;

    // store the character in 
    my_string += ch;
}
```