# Reading a string from hdf5 in C++

Tags: c++, hdf5

I am reading in datasets from a H5 file in Microsoft Visual C++ 2008. Everything works fine for data of type int and double but I run into problems when I come across strings. In the H5 file I have 18 strings each of fixed length 24. My code is as follows;

```
StrType strdatatype(PredType::C_S1, 24);
char *buffer1[18];
DataSet datasetCurveNames = riskFactorsH5.openDataSet("/gstrCurveNames");

datasetCurveNames.read(&buffer1, strdatatype);
```

On execution buffer1 is filled with bad pointers. As an alternative I have tried using H5T_VARIABLE to manage variable length strings with the modification:

```
 StrType strdatatype(PredType::C_S1, H5T_VARIABLE);
```

This also fails. If anyone can shed some light on this issue it would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Lucas

Answer (score 9):

The HDF5 C++ API is woefully under-documented.  This is how I read in strings from a dataset.  I only figured this out with the help of a code-completion IDE:

```
using namespace H5;
std::string field_name("name of the field");
StrType datatype(0, H5T_VARIABLE);
DataSpace dataspace(H5S_SCALAR);
DataSet datset = group.openDataSet(field_name);

std::string field_value;
datset.read(field_value, datatype, dataspace);
```

Comment: How does this work? when is the memory for `field_value` allocated?

Comment: @Walter The std::string class contains its own memory management. You can create an std::string and just assign it a C-string. It will resize its internal array to appropriately store the data. Or you can call std::string::resize directly to change the size of the internal memory array and assign character-by-character.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9521629/950677 for more on std::string and its memory.

Comment: I know all that. What I didn't know is that `DataSet::read()` assigns a C-string. Is this obvious from the datatype? (not for me).

Comment: There is an overload of H5::DataSet::read that takes a reference to a H5std_string as its argument (http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/class_h5_1_1_data_set.html#a507862244d09bd87f66c9e91cb09e104). H5std_string is just a typedef around std::string (on most systems; presumably there are special cases that gave rise to the H5std_string typedef). The fact that it takes a mutable reference to an std::string (not a const ref) is what implies that it reads into an std::string. If the API takes a std::string, then one would not expect it to require pre-allocation

Comment: Okay, I verified that this worked ... in theory. But in practice it won't work for me (because the hdf5 C++ library I can use as been compiled with gcc 4.X while I use 5.1 when I get undefined references to anything using `std::string`, which in the library is `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >` but in my code `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >`). So, what is the way to do this without calling `DataSet::read(std::string&, ...)`?

Comment: @Walter If you are having troubles like that, I'd either switch compilers, find/make a different build of HDF5, or abandon the C++ interface altogether and use the C interface. See https://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/examples-by-api/hdf5-examples/1_8/C/H5T/h5ex_t_string.c for an example reading a string using the C interface. You can also look at `void H5::DataSet::read( H5std_string& strg, ...)` in https://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/unpacked/c++/src/H5DataSet.cpp (it's just a thin wrapper around the C interface)

Comment: thanks for your thoughts. I now understand the issue better (after reading [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html)).

Comment: @Walter I had no idea that the g++ 5.1 ABI had changed. That's great information to have!

Comment: Nice find. H5T_VARIABLE and related concepts are documented in the [HDF5's User Guide](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/UG/HDF5_Users_Guide-Responsive%20HTML5/index.html#t=HDF5_Users_Guide%2FDatatypes%2FHDF5_Datatypes.htm%23TOC_6_6_1_Stringsbc-16&rhtocid=6.4.0_1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for the full strings, the library won't do it for you. You should replace

```
char *buffer1[18];
```

by

```
char buffer1[18][24];
```

and

```
datasetCurveNames.read(&buffer1, strdatatype);
```

should be

```
datasetCurveNames.read(buffer1, strdatatype);
```

(no `&`)

Answer (score 0):

```
    auto dataset = file.openDataSet(kDatasetName);
    auto dataspace = dataset.getSpace();
    hsize_t dims_out[2];
    auto ndims = dataspace.getSimpleExtentDims(dims_out, nullptr);
    assert(ndims == 2);
    auto n = dims_out[0] * dims_out[1];
    auto data_type = dataset.getDataType();
    auto type_class = data_type.getClass();
    auto data_size = data_type.getSize();
    void* out = new char[n * data_size]();
    dataset.read(out, data_type);
    if (type_class == H5T_INTEGER) {
    } else if (type_class == H5T_STRING) {
      std::string* strs = new std::string[n];
      for (auto i = 0u; i < n; ++i) {
        auto len = data_size;
        auto c_str = out + data_size * i;
        for (auto p = c_str + len - 1; p != c_str && !*p; --p) --len;
        strs[i].assign(c_str, len);
      }
    }
    free(out);
```

Checkout https://github.com/opentradesolutions/openalpha/blob/hdf5/src/openalpha/data.cc for full example